# How to set my colorbar to have the same limits on all axes in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot with 4 different axes that display data from different horizontal and vertical resolutions. I would like to compare these data sets, but I noticed that all of the colorbars have different limits to them. [image]

How would I go about making the colorbar limits uniform among all axes? I tried plt.clim, but apparently I need an plt.imshow, and I'm not exactly sure how to go about getting it. Is there a better way to go about this? I already have some code that determines which dataset should set the colorbar limits, and what those limits should be, I just need to know what would successfully adjust the colorbar for all axes.

Some example code for the colorbar (in this instance for the fourth axes):

```
colorbar_div4 = fig.colorbar(div4_contourf, ax=ax3, orientation='vertical')
colorbar_div4.set_label('1/s', fontsize=12)
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Define ``vmax`` and ``vmin`` and add it along this line: ``fig.colorbar(...)``

Comment: @Karina I attempted this solution, but I got an error stating that __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'vmin'

Comment: Set the same vmin/vmax on your pcolormesh or contour artists.  Or share a norm among them.

Comment: I don't see the reason why it throws out that error. Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: @karina vmin and vmax should be as parameters to ax.contourf not to fig.colorbar

Comment: @JohanC right, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
In [56]: x =np.linspace(0, 355/113, 101)
    ...: X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)
    ...: Z = np.sin(X-Y)+np.cos(X+Y)
    ...: norm = plt.Normalize(Z.min(), Z.max()+3) # plus 3 because I add one at end of loop
    ...: fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2,constrained_layout=1)
    ...: for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    ...:     pcm = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, shading='auto', norm=norm); plt.colorbar(pcm, ax=ax)
    ...:     Z = Z.T+1
```

You ① find the minimum and the maximum of the four data arrays, ② find the minimimum of the minima and the maximum of the maxima, ③ instantiate a `Normalize` class that spans this range, and ④ happily plot your data, just remember to pass your `norm` to the plotting method.